# In Ubuntu GNOME, switching the keyboard layout lights the LED light

Tags: gnome, keyboard

When I want to change the language, I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>. Then the green light (LED) for Scroll Lock on the keyboard lights up.

In Ubuntu Unity 16.04 this was not the case.

Now I have Ubuntu GNOME 17.04. It is much better than Unity, but this problem with LED just makes me angry. Eyes are already aching from the fact that something blinks to the right every time.

How do I fix it?

Comment: for more information
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035383/on-input-source-change-the-scroll-lock-toggles

Answer (score 2):

It is normal. It was set by ubiquity installer (or during upgrade) in `/etc/default/keyboard`.

I guess you should change

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

to

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

Then update initramfs with `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` (to change this in console sessions) and reboot.