# On input source change the scroll lock toggles

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I updated my Ubuntu to 18.04 and now when I change the input language (either with the shortcut or by selecting the language from the top right) the scroll lock toggles, which causes my keyboard to turn on and off the blacklight every time I change the input language. I tried to replace the

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

to

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

from `/etc/default/keyboard` but didn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You run into [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1762952).

That `grp_led:scroll` option gets imported to dconf too. Since you already removed the option from `/etc/default/keyboard`, a simple way to fix it is through this command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. + after opening a terminal it started to blink again.

This worked for me:

First change `/etc/default/keyboard` - as above:

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

to

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

Than remove from `.profile` , `.bashrc` etc any calls to

```
setxkbmap ...
```

(I had `setxkbmap -option 'numpad:microsoft'`)